# Based on Condition Extract Values Right of String

Tags: sql, sql-server, case-when, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a dataset in sql that looks like this:

```
    Col1    Col2
 13_DND_       5
   _DND_       6
123_ETL_      10
    ETL_      12
    DND_      15
   _ETL_      17
```

If Col1 contains either `_DND_` or `_ETL_`, I want to remove everything to the left of `DND_` and `ETL_`.

Final expected output is below:

```
        Col1    Col2         Col3
  13_DND_456       5      DND_456
   _DND_de1f       6     DND_de1f
123_ETL_mene      10     ETL_mene
    ETL_test      12     ETL_test 
      DND_se      15       DND_se
   _ETL_def_      17     ETL_def_
```

I tried below for 1 condition but the result was NULL:

```
SELECT *, CASE WHEN Col1 LIKE '%_DND_%' 
THEN RIGHT(Col1, LENGTH(Col1) - CHARINDEX('DND_', Col1)) ELSE Col1 END Col3;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would be inclined to use `STUFF()`:

```
select (case when col1 like '%[_]DND%'
             then stuff(col1, 1, charindex('_DND', col1) - 1, '')
             when col1 like '%[_]END%'
             then stuff(col1, 1, charindex('_END', col1) - 1, '')
             else col1
        end) as col3
```

Your code doesn't work because the `LIKE` fails unless "DND" starts at the second position.  So, it is returning `NULL`.

Because `_` is a wildcard in `LIKE`, the `LIKE` pattern escapes it.

Comment: Thanks, I am using Snowflake so the `STUFF` function does not work in this case unfortunately. Do you know another function that could possibly work?

Comment: @nak5120 . . . Your question is tagged "sql-server" and `stuff()` is definitely supported by that database.

Comment: You're right I didn't specify, next time I will. I'll give you the correct answer since it works for SQL server

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to use wildcards with LIKE.

Instead of this:

```
SELECT *, CASE WHEN Col1 LIKE '_DND_'
```

You want this:

```
SELECT *, CASE WHEN Col1 LIKE '%_DND_%'
```

Comment: It should be noted that `_` itself is also a wildcard (any single character)

Comment: @PeterB true, although it will work anyway, you would need to escape the underscore character to match it literally.

Comment: can you write the full query out for this? I think this is close to what I need

Answer (score 0):

This works for my needs:

```
SELECT *, CASE WHEN Col1 LIKE '%_DND_%' OR Col1 LIKE '%_ETL_%'
THEN RIGHT(Col1, length(Col1) - charindex('-', Col1)) ELSE Col1 END Col3 FROM DF;
```

Answer (score 0):

The shortest I can think of is simply `REGEXP_REPLACE`:

```
select col1, regexp_replace(col1, '.*_(ETL|DND)_', '\\1_') from x;
--------------+-----------------------------------------------+
     COL1     | REGEXP_REPLACE(COL1, '.*_(ETL|DND)_', '\\1_') |
--------------+-----------------------------------------------+
 13_DND_456   | DND_456                                       |
 345DND_7658  | 345DND_7658                                   |
 123_ETL_mene | ETL_mene                                      |
 _ETL_def_    | ETL_def_                                      |
 123ETL_mene  | 123ETL_mene                                   |
--------------+-----------------------------------------------+
--------------+-----------------------------------------+
```

Building on Gordon's asnwer:

```
select col1, (case when col1 like '%^_DND%' escape '^'
             then substr(col1, charindex('_DND', col1) + 1)
             when col1 like '%^_END%' escape '^'
             then substr(col1, charindex('_END', col1) + 1)
             else col1
        end) as col3 from x;
--------------+--------------+
     COL1     |     COL3     |
--------------+--------------+
 13_DND_456   | DND_456      |
 345DND_7658  | 345DND_7658  |
 123_ETL_mene | 123_ETL_mene |
 _ETL_def_    | _ETL_def_    |
 123ETL_mene  | 123ETL_mene  |
--------------+--------------+
```